# How to prompt for database password when running Laravel 5 migrations

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel migrations need to be run with a particularly high level of privilege, as they perform DDL operations.  I would like to run migrations as a named user without storing the password anywhere.  This will require prompting the user for their password when they run the migration from the command-line.  I cannot find any way to achieve this via connection configuration.

Is there a way to achieve this via the connection configuration?

If not, is there a way to perform the migrations with a thin layer of custom code over the top to establish the database connection in a custom manner?  e.g. write a script/artisan command that does the prompting, connects to the DB, and then delegates the rest to Laravel's existing migration code?

Comment: So you would like to use an already configured connection from `config/database.php` but specify a different database user and password when running the migration from the console?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your requirement is to just ask the user for database credentials in order to run the migrations, then this can very easily be achieved by wrapping the `artisan migrate` command within another command that asks for appropriate credentials. So the steps below should suffice:

**1.** Create the new command:

```php
artisan make:console MigratePrivilegedCommand --command="migrate:privileged"
```

**2.** Add the necessary code to handle user input and run the migrations in your new command class:

```php
class MigratePrivilegedCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'migrate:privileged';
    protected $description = 'Run migrations as a priviledged database user.';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // Set the username and password for the
        // database connection from user input
        config([
            'database.connections.mysql.username' => $this->ask('What is your username?'),
            'database.connections.mysql.password' => $this->secret('What is your password?')
        ]);

        // Call the migrate command and you're done    
        $this->call('migrate');
    }
}
```

**3.** Register the new command in `App\Console\Kernel.php`:

```php
protected $commands = [
    ...
    \App\Console\Commands\MigratePrivilegedCommand::class,
];
```

And now you can run migrations that need privileged database credentials with this:

```
php artisan migrate:privileged
```

Comment: Ok. But what if that user will just use `php artisan migration` command?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Then the migrations will fail because of the lack of database privileges for the database connection user that is configured by default.

Comment: Still don't get it. There are default mysql (for example) settings, app will not work without these default settings. Those defaults are used by `migrate` command. User still have access to `migrate` command. So, why user can't just use `migrate` command?

Comment: The question doesn't say that a user can't try to run `php artisan migrate`, it just says that he wants to be able to run migrations using some credentials that he does not want stored anywhere. That means that there can be a connection defined in `config/database.php` (which in my answer I named generically `mysql`) with some values required for the migration to work, but with a blank username an password. For the migrations to work the user must enter a valid username/password. Other connections defined there would not have enough DB privileges and would just error out.

Comment: Come on, why on earth someone would want a solution when **any user** can just do migrations and not only the one **who knows the password**?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin this is becoming annoying. I don't understand why you're arguing about my answer without knowing the OPs intent, let him be the one who decides whether my answer is valid or not.

Comment: Did not know this was possible, great answer Mr. Bogdan.

Comment: To clear up the debate: this is exactly what I had in mind in my last paragraph, I just didn't know if it was possible or how to implement it.  Thank you for the very detailed response--made my life a lot easier.

Comment: @MichaelRusch, just want to be sure, do you understand that any user will be able to run migrations without knowing password with `php artisan migrate` command? If it's really what you want, why you even need the solution? It's really interesting, as I can't imagine any scenario where you want to protect something with password and at the same time allow anyone to do the same without password.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin you seem to miss the point here, so I've explained the scenario in detail here [http://pastebin.com/CsG03xe7](http://pastebin.com/CsG03xe7), since a comment would not allow for enough text. If that still won't clear things for you I don't know what will.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom connection without any password in the config file and pass the password via CLI command to run the migrations.

In database.php config

```
'connection_without_password' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'hostname,
            'database'  => 'database',
            'username'  => '$username',
            'password'  => '$password',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

Schema class includes a connection name option.

```
Schema::connection('connection_without_password')->create('users', function ($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
});
```